# Notation for a region $R=[0,2]×[0,4$] when calculating double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, notation

Can someone explain this notation.

I understand that in the $x$ direction it is a closed interval from $0$ to $2$ and in the $y$ direction it is a closed interval from $0$ to $4$. 
But why do we take the cross product?

Comment: $R = [0,2] \times [0,4]$ is not the cross product, it stands for the *set* of all pairs of real numbers $(x,y)$ such that $x \in [0,2]$ and $y \in [0,4]$, in other words, $R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 \leq x \leq 2 \ \& \ 0 \leq y \leq 4\}$. For example, $(1,3) \in R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we integrate a univariate function $f(x)$ over a region $R=[0,2]$, this means to calculate:
$$\int_0^2 f(x) dx$$

Likewise, when we  integrate a bivariate function $f(x,y)$ over a region $R=[0,2] \times [0,4]$, this means to calculate:
$$\int_0^4\int_0^2 f(x,y) dx dy$$

In other words, you integrate $dx$ with respect to $x$'s range, then integrate that $dy$ with respect to $y$'s range. (Or vice versa, doing it the other way is fine too)

Comment: thank you Rhys! so the x is just normal multiplication then

Comment: Exactly! In this case, the region is a rectangle.